# Can't install libsdl2-dev:i386 on Ubuntu 17.04 64 bit alongside libsdl2-dev:amd64

Tags: 17.04, multiarch, sdl

Output when I try to install libsdl2-dev:i386

```
tony@tony-ubuntu:/$ sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libsdl2-dev:i386 : Depends: libegl1-mesa-dev:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libgles2-mesa-dev:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libmirclient-dev:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxkbcommon-dev:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
tony@tony-ubuntu:/$
```

If I try manual install of libxkbcommon-dev:i386, I get this

```
tony@tony-ubuntu:/$ sudo apt-get install libxkbcommon-dev:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libasound2-dev libdbus-1-dev libdrm-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglib2.0-dev
  libglib2.0-dev-bin libglu1-mesa-dev libibus-1.0-dev libice-dev libmircookie-dev
  libmircore-dev libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libprotobuf-dev
  libpthread-stubs0-dev libpulse-dev libsdl2-2.0-0 libsm-dev libsndio-dev libsndio6.1
  libudev-dev libwayland-bin libwayland-dev libx11-dev libx11-doc libx11-xcb-dev
  libxau-dev libxcb-dri2-0-dev libxcb-dri3-dev libxcb-glx0-dev libxcb-present-dev
  libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-sync-dev
  libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxcb1-dev libxcursor-dev libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev
  libxfixes-dev libxi-dev libxinerama-dev libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev libxshmfence-dev
  libxss-dev libxt-dev libxv-dev libxxf86vm-dev mesa-common-dev x11proto-core-dev
  x11proto-damage-dev x11proto-dri2-dev x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-gl-dev
  x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev x11proto-randr-dev x11proto-render-dev
  x11proto-scrnsaver-dev x11proto-video-dev x11proto-xext-dev x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev
  x11proto-xinerama-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev zlib1g-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED
  libegl1-mesa-dev libgles2-mesa-dev libmirclient-dev libmircommon-dev libsdl2-dev
  libxkbcommon-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libxkbcommon-dev:i386
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 6 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
Need to get 303 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,506 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

To which I reply 'n' because I really don't want to remove all that stuff...!

Do you know why libxkbcommon-dev:i386 is not happy to live alongside all these 64 bit dev libraries?

Comment: because it is 32 bit. why are you trying to install a 32-bit library? do you have multiarch enabled?

Comment: Yes have multiarch enabled. I have both versions of libsdl2-2.0 installed, and 32/64 bit g++. I'm trying to build 32 and 64 bit SDL programs on a 64 bit machine. Compilation works but I can't link due to missing SDL library.

Comment: hmmm, with multiarch it should be ok. perhaps apt can't resolve because 32 bit breaks 64 bit.  have you tried from `aptitude` it is pretty good at showing what is going on.  PS all those unused libraries don't need to be kept